# Как отловить браузерный поиск (ctrl+F)?

Tags: javascript

1. Как отловить само событие и получить параметры поиска? Можно ли
   предотвратить скролл на странице в этот момент?
2. Как отловить выставление текущего активного элемента из списка
   выделенных элементов? На скриншоте ниже ищу "По" найдено 79
   элементов двигаюсь вниз по элементам нажимая на стрелки вверх вниз
   из формы поиска браузерной и цвет выделения с желтого становится
   оранжевым. Вот как поймать событие когда текущий становится активным и можно ли это вообще?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Явного события нету, как вариант.. можно ловить событие onscroll, и в новой версии плюс onselectionchange, или по-таймеру опрашивать свойство selection.

Comment: Во, теперь у нас есть производственные показатели РЖД)

Answer (score 0):

Такого события нет, но можно отловить нажатие этой комбинации с помощью такой функции -

```html
document.onkeydown = function(e){
 if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 70){
  alert('CTRL+F Detected!');
 return false;}
}
```

Comment: 1) А если мышкой? 2) а если окно висит с прошлого сеанса поиска? (Я в гугле нажал Ctrl+F перешел на нужный сайт - окно поиска внизу висит)

Comment: Не, это не подходит совсем. Гарантии нет.

Comment: Запретить правый клик мышки?